# Optimizing strContains for speed

Tags: string, performance, hash, contains

I have a function(pattern1, pattern2) which iterates through two strings like this

```
       for (int i = 0; i <= len; i+=8)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= len - i; j+=8)
            {
                subpattern = pattern1.Substring(i, j);
                ..
```

What I have to check is if pattern2.Contains(subpattern).
For the sake of testing i've loaded a huge stream (.jpg file) of ~100KB as patterns. In case it doesn't contain, it will just call break;

Now this code finishes in ~5.5kms on average. I tried to optimize with almost anything that I could come up with but no success.

What I tried was:

```
        HashSet<string> positive = new HashSet<string>();
        HashSet<string> negative = new HashSet<string>();
```

Every time the pattern2 contained subpattern I added it to the "positive" hash, else added to the negative. I checked first if negative hash contained the pattern, in case it did I called break;

In case that was false, I checked if the positive hash contained the pattern, if yes I did what I had to do and then called continue;

In case the pattern wasn't found in neither positive or negative, I checked if pattern2.Contains(subpattern) and depending on the outcome added the new subpattern to either the positive or negative hash

This increased the speed by exactly 0 miliseconds... But I can't wrap my head around why? Theoretically and statistically it should have increased the speed by at least a little? I tried using only the positive and only the negative hash, different check orders (positive > negative > contains) (negative > positive > contains) but I still get 5.5k ms~ every time.

I've tried using a SortedSet too because it's .Contains() implements a binary search as far as I know, this lead to an average speed of 6k ms~ due to the constant sorting.

List performed terribly with over 8kms~

Did I overlook something obvious? Ofcourse increasing the increment of i,j makes it faster but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Sorry to be nitpicking, but 5k ms = 5 s

Comment: The theory that String.Contains() is flawed and can be improved is deeply flawed.  Ultimately code like this is bounded by the speed of the memory bus, not the algorithm.  A fixed number that can only be improved with dollars.  Also the core reason why theoretically faster string comparison algorithms like Boyer-Moore are not used in practice.